# MQTT works only in one device

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I've made an Ionic PWA mqtt that publishes via a websocket, but when I deploy the app (I'm using AWS), it only works in Google Chrome, if I test it in an Incognito window, it doesn't work.

In the console it show this error on all devices (pc/mobile) that aren't working:

> bSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org:8081/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Below is my javascript Ionic code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MQTTService } from 'ionic-mqtt';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  private _mqttClient: any;
  temp = 19;

  private MQTT_CONFIG: {
    host: string,
    port: number,
    clientId: string,
    path: string,
  } = {
    host: "test.mosquitto.org",
    port: 8081,
    clientId: "qeekljeqe" + Math.floor(Math.random()*100),
    path: "/",
  };

  private TOPIC: string[] = [];

  constructor(private _mqttService: MQTTService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._mqttClient = this._mqttService.loadingMqtt(this._onConnectionLost, this._onMessageArrived, this.TOPIC, this.MQTT_CONFIG);
  }

  private _onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
    // connection listener
    // ...do actions when connection lost
    console.log('_onConnectionLost', responseObject);
  }

  private _onMessageArrived(message) {
    // message listener
    // ...do actions with arriving message
    console.log('message', message);  
}
public publishMessage(TOPICO : string, VALOR : string) {
  console.log('publishMessage')
  this._mqttService.publishMessage(TOPICO, VALOR);
}
```

Comment: Now i cant really find a solution to your problem. But i can tell you my implementation on a similar app (I wanted to send a message into an mqtt broker from a SPA). 

The SPA would talk to a REST API (The same api it authenticates and does CRUD for it), and the api would then send the message into the broker. In that way the SPA only does a Http Post operation thats universal. While the API can implement the required code to talk with the broker.

Simpler, safer(becouse you can authenticate the calls) and more maintainable.

Comment: I found a solution, I ran mosquitto on EC2 AWS and config it, your project is robust? I'm afraid that using MQTT with esp dont endure what I want

Comment: Yeah. Its pretty solid. The sonoff series uses esp8266 based devices with mqtt protocol too. Maybe you should check  your devices code and or library. What problems you have?